# VBA string comparison failure

Tags: string, vba, excel, string-comparison

i met interesting issue when im comparing two strings. Im reading data from file and everything works well. But then co-worker send me input file, which is just CTRL+C and CTRL+V of working file. And then miracle happend! VBA is so confused, that cant compare two simple strings and i fell of chair.

If you take a look at image you can see that comparison passed if condition where are two same strings, but it should not. Im a bit confused how this can happen.

[image]

So met someone something like this? Im realy start thinking about something like machine revolution from Terminator. (files are both saved in notepad++ and there are no strange characters or something like that)

**Progress update**
So i tried hints from guys in comments below. and ended with something like this

```
If CStr(Trim(rowArray(4))) <> (CStr("N/A")) Then
```

Contentent of rowArray(4) is still "N/A" string as on picture above and excel still thinks this strings arent same. I also saved file in pspad, netbeans, and normal notepad and issue is still same.

Comment: please embed your code into the post, instead of in a picture and we also cannot see what is underneath the `rowArray(4)-"N/A"`, which could be important to solving the issue.

Comment: Have you tried **`If CStr(rowArray(4)) <> CStr("N/A") Then`** ?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman i needed to send it as picture because of content of rowArray(4) variable. and rest of code is not much important, because issue is in condition

Comment: Notepad++ is a pain for putting whitespace characters in - try using `Trim(rowArray(4))` and see if you get the same result

Comment: @ManishChristian yes i tried that. rowArray variable is already dimed as string, but also i tried your hint and retype it with N/A string, but issue is same. VBA still thinks its different

Comment: @MacroMan i have variable already trimed (whole array) and as you can see on little note above yellow debug pointer, content of rowArray(4) variable is string "N/A" and i comparing it to "N/A" string. No whitespace or something else here.

Comment: @LubošSuk You can't trim a whole array in one go... so not sure what you've done. But anyway, something like `Chr(13)` or `Chr(10)` won't actually show when you hover over the variable, so it will look like there is no whitespace. Just try it - what have you got to lose?

Comment: @MacroMan sorry for my bad interpretation. I did not trimmed whole array in single line, but i looped whole array and trimmed each element. But it doesnt matter, i tried trim and issue is same (i made a little update in question)

Comment: I vaguely remember facing such issues in VBA. I just fixed it by using `InStr` in place of `=`

Comment: @LubošSuk just to see if it's another character that can't be displayed - have you tried doing `?Len(rowArray(4))` in the immediate window and make sure you get `3` as the result?

Comment: Something got messed up, as same line of code working for me. Can you tell us something more about `which is just CTRL+C and CTRL+V of working file`.

Comment: @MacroMan you got the point, len is 4.

Comment: @ManishChristian i have one big file generated by ansys and there i have some values which i wana load. And i take only this values and copy and paste them into another document. Original file can be loaded without problem, but file which i copied throwing this issue. But thanks to MacroMan i see issue with some invisible character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the immediate window to test the contents of the variable:

```
For i = 1 To Len(rowArray(4)): Print Asc(Mid(rowArray(4), i, 1)): Next
```

This will print the ASCII value of each character in the string - you can use this to determine what the extra character(s) are causing the issue.